# Horizontal Pod Autoscaler: which the exact value does HPA take?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, horizontal-scaling, hpa

i have the fowllowing manifests:

The app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hpa-demo-deployment
  labels:
    app: hpa-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hpa-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hpa-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hpa-nginx
        image: stacksimplify/kubenginx:1.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "200m"          
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hpa-demo-service-nginx
  labels:
    app: hpa-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: hpa-nginx
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

and its HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa-demo-declarative
spec:
  maxReplicas: 10 # define max replica count
  minReplicas: 1  # define min replica count
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: hpa-demo-deployment
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 20 # target CPU utilization
```

Notice in HPA, the target CPU is set to 20%

My question: which 20% the HPA takes ? is it requests.cpu (ie: 100m) ? or limits.cpu (ie: 200m) ? or something else ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its based off of the `resources.requests.cpu`.

> For per-pod resource metrics (like CPU), the controller fetches the metrics from the resource metrics API for each Pod targeted by the HorizontalPodAutoscaler. Then, if a target utilization value is set, the controller calculates the utilization value as a **percentage of the equivalent resource request on the containers in each Pod**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-a-horizontalpodautoscaler-work

Comment: i did not see that ^^